# Align ImageView with TextView in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout

[image: image test for question]

I have this composition with which I am testing the use of chains, but I have a doubt, that way, using Constraint Layout, could I align the TextView from above with the ImageView from below? Without the TextView above moving from its position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test__label__text_top"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/test__label__text_bot"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="Texto superior" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test__img__image_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/test__label__text_bot"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test__label__text_top"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test__label__text_bot"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/test__img__image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test__label__text_top"
        tools:text="Texto inferior" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change ImageView constraints to:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test__img__image_view"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/test__label__text_top"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test__label__text_top"
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

and it should work like you describe.

Comment: You're right. You're right. I got into a mess with the chains and I didn't remember that even if I have a vertical chain I can still place the elements horizontally. Thanks.